# Putnam 2007 - Exercise B.2 - Clarification on hypothesis

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, contest-math, taylor-expansion

**CONTEXT**

The problem is the following.

**Suppose that $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ has a continuous derivative
and that $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = 0$. Prove that for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$,
$$
\left| \int_0^\alpha f(x)\,dx \right| \leq \frac{1}{8} \max_{0 \leq x
\leq 1} |f'(x)|.
$$**

---

**MY APPROACH**

Let $\max_{0\leq x \leq 1} |f'(x)| = M$ and
$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt.$$
Since $F(0) = F(1) = 0$, the minimum and maximum must lie in the open interval $(0,1)$ in points where the derivative is null. Let $\overline x$ one of these points.

Suppose first that $\frac12 \leq \overline x < 1$. Then, by Taylor's Theorem, there exists $\xi$ such that
$$0=F(1) = F(\overline x) + \frac{f'(\xi)}{2}(1-\overline x)^2,\tag{1}\label{1}$$
with $\frac12 \leq \overline x < \xi < 1$. Equation \eqref{1} implies
$$|F(\overline x)| = \frac{(1-\overline x)^2}2|f'(\xi)| \leq \frac18 M.$$

The same approach (expressing $F(0)$ in terms of $F(\overline x)$) can be used if $0<\overline x <\frac12$. The thesis follows.

---

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is my line of thought correct?
2. Is it correct to state that continuity of $f'(x)$ is **not** a necessary condition? (Taylor's Theorem in fact does not require it.)

Comment: Maybe continuity of $f'$ is just to ensure $|f'|$ has a maximum on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: @Mason certainly I agree that boundedness of $f'$ is a necessary condition, for the assertion to hold true.